# Qt Creator parses .sp file as C code

Tags: qt

I'm attempting to get Qt Creator to work with [SourcePawn](https://wiki.alliedmods.net/index.php/Category%3aSourceMod_Development) `.sp` files (ie. highlight syntax correctly at a minimum, possibly get command completion suggestions working) in order to code them more easily, and when I currently open up a .sp file in the IDE it highlights and parses it like a C/C++ file.

Although SourcePawn is C-style there are differences which the IDE doesn't understand, which results in a lot of the code being underlined in green or red. I've looked through the syntax highlighting options and it doesn't appear that there is currently a configuration file that deals with .sp extensions, though my suspicion is that it's more than just syntax highlighting since actual semantic parsing is going on as well.

Is there any way to override how files are parsed by the editor in order to stop .sp files from being interpreted as C/C++?